# Query from secondary index on aerospike

Tags: aerospike, aql, secondary-indexes

I'm considering aerospike for one of our projects. So I currently created a 3 node cluster and loaded some data on it.

Sample data

ns: imei

set: imei_data

```
+-------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+----------------------------+--------------+--------------+
| imsi              | fcheck                | lcheck                | msc                        | fcheck_epoch | lcheck_epoch |
+-------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+----------------------------+--------------+--------------+
| "413010324064956" | "2017-03-01 14:30:26" | "2017-03-01 14:35:30" | "13d20b080011044917004100" | 1488358826   | 1488359130   |
| "413012628090023" | "2016-09-21 10:06:49" | "2017-09-16 13:54:40" | "13dc0b080011044917006100" | 1474432609   | 1505550280   |
| "413010130130320" | "2016-12-29 22:05:07" | "2017-10-09 16:17:10" | "13d20b080011044917003100" | 1483029307   | 1507546030   |
| "413011330114274" | "2016-09-06 01:48:06" | "2017-10-09 11:53:41" | "13d20b080011044917003100" | 1473106686   | 1507530221   |
| "413012629781993" | "2017-08-16 16:03:01" | "2017-09-13 18:10:48" | "13dc0b080011044917004100" | 1502879581   | 1505306448   |
```

Then I created a secondary index on lcheck_epoch using AQL since I want to query based on date.

`create index idx_lcheck on imei.imei_data (lcheck_epoch) NUMERIC`

```
+--------+----------------+-----------+-------------+-------+--------------+----------------+-----------+
| ns     | bin            | indextype | set         | state | indexname    | path           | type      |
+--------+----------------+-----------+-------------+-------+--------------+----------------+-----------+
| "imei" | "lcheck_epoch" | "NONE"    | "imei_data" | "RW"  | "idx_lcheck" | "lcheck_epoch" | "NUMERIC" |
+--------+----------------+-----------+-------------+-------+--------------+----------------+-----------+
```

When I execute

`select imsi from imei.imei_data where idx_lcheck=1476165806`

I'm getting

`Error: (204) AEROSPIKE_ERR_INDEX`

Please explain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the index name, not the bin name, in your query. Try this:

```
SELECT imsi FROM imei.imei_data WHERE lcheck_epoch=1476165806
```

Or

```
SELECT imsi FROM imei.imei_data WHERE lcheck_epoch BETWEEN 1490000000 AND 1510000000
```

Just a note, you can do much more complex queries using [predicate filtering](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/predicate.html) through several of the language clients (Java, C, C#, Go). For example the [PredExp](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/java/com/aerospike/client/query/PredExp.html) class of the Java client (see [examples](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-java/blob/master/examples/src/com/aerospike/examples/QueryPredExp.java).)

Comment: Thank you so much. at first when I executed SELECT imsi FROM imei.imei_data WHERE lcheck_epoch='1476165806'; it gave me Error: (201) AEROSPIKE_ERR_INDEX_NOT_FOUND. Should be because i used quotes.

Comment: Just two side questions. 1) does aerospike have an equivalent to mysql : select field1, field2 into out file '/tmp/file' from imei where lcheck_epoch>1476165806 since i have to send a csv dump of daily updated records to another system. and in above question is lcheck_epoch>1476165806 a valid filter?

Comment: Yes, the quotes would turn it into a string, and you don't have a secondary index on that bin for STRING data, yours is NUMERIC. There's no automatic typecasting.

Comment: Regarding a CSV dump, there was a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45819023/how-to-parse-aerospike-backup-file-to-regenerate-data  - the short of it is that I suggest you use asbackup and asrestore, which will be faster, generate more compact data, than a homegrown CSV backup script. Between systems you should consider Kafka and the Aerospike Kafka connector.